# Gnome-terminal linux mint startup command

Tags: linux-mint, gnome-terminal

How do you edit gnome-terminal startup command?

Someone put `gnome-terminal && clear` in my startup command box in the preferences panel on linuxmint.

How do I either edit the preferences or find the file with the command in it?

Answer (score 1):

Haha! If you've done this run an invalid command for gnome-terminal...

- Press `Alt + F2`
- type `gnome-terminal -e ":)"`

You should get an error message at the top of a STATIC (finally) terminal that says `Failed to execute child process ":)" (no such file or directory)`.

Done... (right after you either right click and go to `Profiles > Preferenes` or click on the `Profile Preferences` button at the top and edit your preferences so that you can open your terminal correctly)

:)